# Web-scraping www.wp.pl

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, rvest

I want to use R to get some info from the https://www.wp.pl/ page.
I want to get the element:

```
<div class="_1bBIQG" data-st-area="Belka-opinions">
```

On the screen it will be the first box below the add:
[image]

I am using *rvest* library.
Here's my code so far:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.wp.pl'
webpage <- read_html(url)
news_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'._1gA4wm.content div div ul li a')
head(news_html)
```

But it does not work. I get the news below that.
How do I scrape it?

Comment: You seem to be in violation of III. 3. iii. & iv. http://onas.wp.pl/zasady.html

Comment: It is just an exercise. I do not mean to use it anywhere, so I do not think to be in violation of their policy.

Comment: Hopefully that convinces others to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. I get the list of links just fine.

Alternatively, try:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.wp.pl'
webpage <- read_html(url)
links <- webpage %>% html_nodes("div._1gA4wm.content div div ul li a")
links
```

Also, if you'd rather have the full contents of the `div`, try:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.wp.pl'
webpage <- read_html(url)
my_div <- webpage %>% html_node("div._1gA4wm.content")
my_div
```